# Symmetric matrices of the same rank are 'related'

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two complex symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ having the same rank, how would I show there is an invertible matrix $S$ satisfying:

$B=S^{\rm T}AS$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follows from the Autonne-Takagi factorization.